# You need to provide an instance of SwaggerBundleConfiguration in Dropwizard

Tags: java, swagger, dropwizard

I am using swagger with dropwizard by using this module https://github.com/smoketurner/dropwizard-swagger

I have followed all the relevant steps and When I a running the app I am getting this error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to provide an instance of
> SwaggerBundleConfiguration

I got a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569273/adding-swagger-to-dropwizard-application-need-to-provide-instance-of-swaggerbun) .And added following lines to the `config.yml` file

```
swagger:
  resourcePackage: io.demo.backendservices.resources
```

But still its not working.Any help please

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you did not create SwaggerBundleConfiguration instance in your Configuration class? I've created dropwizard project example using swagger and all other things, maybe you can check it out and see if it helps you. The project is in here:

https://github.com/rsatrio/dropwizard-modern-example